# php: combining variable values of the same type?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to PHP coming over from Javascript.  I have 2 PHP methods.  I'd like to combine them into one endpoint call.  Can I push them into the same Array so they can come back in one call with one payload?

```
public function incompleteOrders()
{
    $orders = request()->user()->incompleteOrders();

    $data = $orders->toArray();

    return response($data, 200);
}

public function finishedOrders()
{
    $orders = request()->user()->finishedOrders();

    $data = $orders->toArray();

    return response($data, 200);
}
```

Comment: You definitely can do this, but you haven't specified the format you want to use, nor have you shown what you've tried so far. Please read about [ask] questions here and show your effort so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple keys on the resulting json object, for example:

```php
public function orders()
{
    $data = [
        'incomplete' => request()->user()->incompleteOrders(),
        'finished' => request()->user()-> finishedOrders(),
    ];

    return response($data, 200);
}
```

The json will look something like this:

```
{
  "finished": [
    {
      "id": 1
    }
  ],
  "incomplete": [
    {
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can fetch the two array and combine them in another array like what we have bellow

```
  public function userOrders()
    {
        $finishedOrders = request()->user()->finishedOrders();
        $incompleteOrders = request()->user()->incompleteOrders();

        $data = ["finishedOrders" => $finishedOrders->toArray(), "incompleteOrders" => $incompleteOrders->toArray()];

        return response($data, 200);
    }
```

Or you can also use `array_merge` a php function to merge the two array in one